# One request per tab or one request for all of them?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My colleague and I are having a debate about loading tab content (jQuery UI Tabs) from the backend. She thinks I should make one AJAX request and index the JSON so that the correct content is filled in the correct tab.

Right now, on the other hand, I'm making one AJAX request per tab where one of the arguments is the tab ID, this simplifies the task of putting the retrieved content in to the requested tab.

I have 6 tabs in total. What do you think guys?

Comment: Obviously it's better to do one request rather then six (assuming the visitor checks all tabs) when thinking of performance.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think that you should rephrase your question - right now it looks rather like invitation  to some sort of discussion, but it should be a straight question requesting a straight answer

Comment: @ninja Well, not obviously. If loading the data for one tab takes 0.5 seconds it's unnoticeable if it's done every time a tab is opened, but a 3 second pause when opening the first one is noticeable.

Comment: There is no correct answer you need to decide based on the amount of data contained in each tab. Also will every user click on every tab if not then why load all six at once.

Comment: If there is big amount of data for each tab, you could make one request only for current tab, loading it faster, and make a second request (async of course) for all other tabs.

Comment: @Juhana Sure, 'obviously' might be pushing it to hard. But usually it's the connection for the request that takes time, not the downloading of the data. So unless we're talking huge amounts of data per tab, one request will most of the times be a better aproach

Comment: statistics matter here. Json object size, data type its holding , data source(db) for json , and how you load the data to each tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, it depends.
If you have only some small amount of data per tab, I would recommend loading all 6 tabs in one request and fill the tabs all together.
If it is a considerable amount of data per tab, I would recommend loading only one tab per request, and only fire those requests when a tab is selected.

When in doubt, you should probably just test both approaches.

Comment: I like the approach "load-as-you-view" to only load the content the user actually views. How do I make it not reload content the second time the user selects a certain tab, i.e. only load on the first tab selection?

Comment: As you are using jQuery UI tabs, you can bind to their events. http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/
you would have to keep some kind of lookup, storing which tabs have already been loaded.
also note, that the events of jQuery UI tabs have changed massively,  keep that in mind if you use an older version of jQuery UI.

Comment: I'm always trying to use the latest version in my projects, so totally cool with that. I'm considering having an array that keeps track of the tabs that have been loaded and not. Thanks for the reply. A+UV.

Comment: And you could detach elements in tabs not currently shown and then re-attach it each time a specific tab is re-shown. This should improve all your functions using DOM transversal methods. Keep the DOM as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the backend type and the usage pattern of your site.

If your users normally views all the tabs, then a single call would be better.
If they rarely sees the tabs or not all of them, the less information you send is better and you could also take advantage of load balancing the ajax requests between webservers.

But all that is true if the content you retrieve for the tabs is not too *heavy* for the backend. In such a situation you must weight the usage pattern (said above) with the processing load and make a decision.

There's not a single *ring to rule them all*.